# The type initializer for 'IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager' threw an exception

Tags: ibm-mq

I am using IBMMQDotnetClient version 9.3.4 in .net7 console application.
I am facing to the below error on MQQueueManager() method. Is there any one who solved this ?

```
The type initializer for 'IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager' threw an exception. | System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager' threw an exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Error reading the  directory. at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEvents() at IBM.WMQ.MQClientCfg.CheckForMqclientIniFileChanges() at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NmqiEnvironment..ctor(NmqiPropertyHandler nmqiPropertyHandler) at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NmqiFactory.GetInstance(NmqiPropertyHandler properties) at IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager.cctor() --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager..ctor(String queueManagerName, Hashtable properties)
```

Comment: Try creating an empty `mqclient.ini` file in the directory where you run the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the above error was relating to IBMMQDotnetClient version 9.3.4 and that error does not exist in version 9.3.1. solved

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: Mr. JoshMc, how can I create the file in the directory ?

Comment: I tried creating a mqclient.ini file - doesn't help unfortunately.  Also tried the latest IBMMQDotnetClient version 9.3.5 - still fails.  But I can confirm that 9.3.1 works fine.